# VBA - to compare 2 tables from 2 sheets, and get result in another sheets creating comparison table

Tags: vba, vlookup

It is above my possibilities.
I know how to create Vba code with Vlookup or Hlookup for single comparision. However whatIi am trying is beyond my knowledge.

I need to compare 2 tables. 1st is requirements where 2nd is DB extract.
Both tables contains same "Action" column and other columns with Employer role as a header. Values from Action column for both tables are the same however in different order ( Those values need to act as primary key).
Columns with Employer role as a header - same header value for both tables - however columns in different order.

Amount of columns with Employer role as a header is not constants and it gets change every time I get this files. Those columns in extract are in different order than in requirements.
Amount of values from "Action" columns ( primary key) also not constants and change every time I receive files. So I cannot set specific range.

Example of Requirements table
[image: Requirements table]
Example of Extract table
[image: Extract table]
Example of what is expected
[image: Comparison table]

1. New target worksheet need to be created where Comparison table will be created.
2. VBA to create Comparison table in newly created worksheet.
   This table should have "Action" column + all columns with Employers role as header form requirements + all columns with Employers role as header form extract set in same order like columns in requirements + comparison table which compare values between Employers roles from Requirements and Extract and show values YES or NO

Comment: I think the question need some more clarifications. Do both first tables have the same 'Action' elements in the same order? If yes, missing of 'Create Note' last row in 'Extract Table` should be considered a tipo? Then, if comparison result must be expressed by a boolean result (True/False), it should be good to have some cases where not everything to be `True`...

Comment: @FaneDuru as i explained above. Action column for both tables elements are the same. However in different order. . So as u see there is "Create Note" element in 'Extract Table' however in different row. Those tables are just examples. Real excel files will have 2500 - 3000 rows of values and 25 -35 columns with same headers however in different order. In this example i show all as TRUE, but i real life there will be some cases where not all will be true. Actually this is reason of this code, to check if extract match with requirements. Hope this explain a bit more. Thank you for response mate.

Comment: OK. Can you also explain what "Example of what is expected` does mean?. Should the 'Extract' part be also contained in the final table, as you show it in he picture? If yes, having an empty column between the entities, it is not a real table. If not, did you only want showing the 'Extrqact' to, to become more relevant the 'Req vs Extract' part which it is only the required part? Or what? Must the result be placed in a table, or it would be enough to be put in a new sheet? And do you say that the headers of both initial tables are not in the same order. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @FaneDuru I provided example how I would like this to be visible for final user. So Requirements and extract are included in Comparison worksheet together with 'Req vs Extract'. So if user want to check values for example for "Regional Manager' "Create Note" action he can see values from Requirements, Extract and boolean values in 'Req vs Extract'.  I would like to have a empty columns between those 3 just to have this visually looks better. However if this is impossible then no.

Comment: Then, it looks that you "Example of Extract table" misses 'SP7' and 'SP8'. If yes, it should be good to be more attentive. Since you did not place editable data and somebody wanting to help try building it according to the picture, it my have a problem and will lose his helping enthusiasm... The values to be matched should be guessed. You could provide a link to such a test workbook, too.

Comment: @FaneDuru updated. Thanks for spotting it. Unfortunately I am not able to provide links for real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It will return in a newly created sheet (after the last existing). The new file is named "New Sheet". If it exists, it is cleared and reused:

```
Sub testMatchTables()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet, shNew As Worksheet
 Dim tbl1 As ListObject, tbl2 As ListObject, rightH As Long
 Dim arrR, arrE, arrH1, arrH2, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
 Dim first As Long, sec As Long, refFirst As Long, refSec As Long
 
 Set sh = Set sh = Worksheets("Requirements")'use here the sheet keeping the first table
 Set sh1 = Worksheets("Extract Table") 'use here your appropriate sheet
 Set tbl1 = sh.ListObjects(1)  'use here your first table name (instead of 1)
 Set tbl2 = sh1.ListObjects(1) 'use here your second table name (instead of 1)
 arrR = tbl1.Range.value 'put the table range in an array
 arrE = tbl2.Range.value 'put the table range in an array
                         'working with arrays will condiderably increase the processing speed
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrR), 1 To UBound(arrR, 2) * 3 + 2) 'redim the array to keep the processing result
                                                       'UBound is a property telling the number of array elements

 arrH1 = Application.Index(arrR, 1, 0) 'make a slice in the array (1D array), the first row, which keeps the headers
 arrH2 = Application.Index(arrE, 1, 0) 'make a slice in the array (1D array), the first row, which keeps the headers

 'build the column headers:
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrFin, 2)
    If i <= UBound(arrH1) Then  'firstly the headers of the first table are filled in the final array
        arrFin(1, i) = arrH1(i)
    ElseIf refSec = 0 Then  'refSec is the column where a blanck column will exist
        first = first + 1   'the code incrementes this variable to allow making empty only for the following row
        If first = 1 Then
            arrFin(1, i) = Empty: refFirst = i 'make the empty column between the two tables data and create a reference
                                               'to be decreated from the already incremented i variable
        Else
            arrFin(1, i) = arrH1(i - refFirst) 'place each header column values
            If i - refFirst = UBound(arrH1) Then refSec = i + 1 'when the code reaches the end of the first array
                                                                'it creates a reference for referencing the second time
        End If
    Else
        sec = sec + 1  'the same philosophy as above, to create the second empty column
        If sec = 1 Then
            arrFin(1, i) = Empty 'create the empty column (for each processed row)
        Else
            arrFin(1, i) = arrH1(i - refSec) 'fill the header columns
        End If
    End If
 Next

 Dim C As Long, r As Long, eT As Long, T As Long
 eT = UBound(arrR)            'mark the ending of the first array (where to be the first empty column)
 T = UBound(arrR, 2) * 2 + 2  'mark the begining of the third final array part
                              'after the second empty column
 For i = 2 To UBound(arrR)    'iterating between the first array rows
    For j = 2 To UBound(arrE) 'iterating the second array rows
        If arrR(i, 1) = arrE(j, 1) Then 'if the both arrays first column matches
             arrFin(i, 1) = arrR(i, 1): arrFin(i, T + 1) = arrR(i, 1) 'put the Action values in the first area columns
             arrFin(i, eT) = arrR(i, 1)   'put the Action values in the last area column
             For C = 2 To UBound(arrR, 2) 'iterate between the array columns
                rightH = Application.match(arrR(1, C), arrH2, 0) 'find the match of the first array header in the second one
                arrFin(i, C) = arrR(i, C): arrFin(i, C + eT - 1) = arrE(j, rightH) 'place the matching header in the final array
                If arrR(i, C) = arrE(j, rightH) Then
                    arrFin(i, T + C) = "TRUE"  'place 'TRUE' in case of matching
                Else
                    arrFin(i, T + C) = "FALSE" 'place 'FALSE' in case of NOT matching
                End If
             Next C
        End If
    Next j
 Next i
 On Error Resume Next    'necessary to return an error if worksheet "New Sheet" does not exist
  Set shNew = Worksheets("New Sheet")
  If err.Number = 9 Then 'if it raises error number 9, this means that the sheet does not exist
    err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0 'clear the error and make the code to return other errors, if any
    Set shNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count)) 'set shNew as new inserted sheet
    shNew.name = "New Sheet"   'name the newly inserted sheet
  Else
    shNew.cells.Clear: On Error GoTo 0 ' in case of sheet exists, it is clear and the code is made to return errors
  End If
 'set the range where the final array to drop its values:
 With shNew.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
    .value = arrFin       'drop the array content
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit 'AutoFit the involved columns
 End With
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

**Edited**:

I commented the code as detailed I could. If still something unclear, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for the time u spend on this. I should receive new files soon  to get this tested. Cant wait. However before i will try to understand and learn from this code. I will provide feedback soon :) Thank You very much

Comment: @Radosław Sokolowski: I will comment everything in a way to be understood. But, I think your thema should involve one table to be bigger and contain all possible cases (the second one) and another one with only some of them, in random position. The final structure which looks logic to me, should involve this last table being the first, then part of the first (the bigger one), referring to only the first one cases. And then the matching analysis...

Comment: I do something wrong here @Fane Duru. I placed expected tables name ex :  Set tbl1 = sh.ListObjects("Requirements Values") but seems that is not correct and not sure about arrR = tbl1.Range.value ? Shall I set Range of whole table like arrR = tbl1.Range("A1:AV3000") ?

Comment: @Radosław Sokolowski:  I am afraid that I do not understand what you mean... A table is a table and setting `tbl1` as I did, it put all the table range in an array. Firstly, did you test my code **on the test workbook you show in your question**? If yes, didn't it work as you need? If not, why didn't you test it? I do not need such a code. I tried understanding what you need and I did it for you...

Comment: Yes. I did test on workbook I show in my question Sir. So i placed expected table names and run code but with no result. 
 Set tbl1 = sh.ListObjects("REQ Values")  'use here your first table name (instead of 1)
 Set tbl2 = sh1.ListObjects("Extr Values") 'use here your second table name (instead of 1.   It ends up with run time error 09 and Set tbl1 is getting highlighted.

Comment: @Radosław Sokolowski: That error only can mean that such a table does not exist in the sheet you try. Please, check what sheet you choose when set `sh1` and if correct, please also check the table name spelling. If your test workbook does not contain any confidential data, can you share it? If yes you can use a transfer site. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) is a free one easy to be used...

Comment: my apologies. I messed up with table name. Your code works great. It creates another sheet and place values over there including comparison table. Great thanks to You. Hope I will get this knowledge You present one day :) Thank You

Comment: @Radosław Sokolowski: Glad I (finally) could help! As I promised, I will try commenting all the code lines in a way to be understood from somebody less experienced, too. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: is there any way to modified this code so it would also work with #N/A values? I just see that sometimes Extract tables contains row with #N/A values as part previous VLOOKUP function. Size of tables does not change at all. It just some values for particular ACTION exists in "Requirements" but are not populated in Extract. in this case when comparing for example value YES with #N/A result should remain #N/A